# Batch script search path value in registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, registry

Some registry data values contains strings with windows path for example like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test]
"30-Jan-19-15:49:55.31-23207"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\image 1 (2).png"
"30-Jan-19-16:46:50.12-19158"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\image1 (2).png"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:11.27-19621"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\image1(2).png"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:12.27-19623"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\Folder2"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:32.37-19663"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\Folder2\\image5.png"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:37.57-19163"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\Folder2\\image8.png"
"30-Jan-19-16:51:31.27-10621"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder2\\mytext1(2).txt"
"30-Jan-19-16:56:11.27-19111"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder2\\mytext2(3).txt"
"30-Jan-19-16:59:01.27-14521"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder3\\myaudio3.mp3"
"30-Jan-19-16:59:41.27-19135"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder3\\myaudio5.mp3"
```

I want to find values which matches with parent folder and remove them. For example I do pass folder `C:\Test folder\Newfolder` and this registry data should be found and removed:

```
"30-Jan-19-15:49:55.31-23207"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\image 1 (2).png"
"30-Jan-19-16:46:50.12-19158"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\image1 (2).png"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:11.27-19621"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\image1(2).png"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:12.27-19623"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\Folder2"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:32.37-19663"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\Folder2\\image5.png"
"30-Jan-19-16:49:37.57-19163"="C:\\Test folder\\Newfolder\\Folder2\\image8.png"
```

I tried to find registry values first which matched with specified string for example `pathtosearch=C:\Test folder\Newfolder` but no values matched. What is wrong with script? And how to correct found registry values and delete them?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "val="
set "pathtosearch=C:\Test folder\Newfolder"

echo.
set "hkey=HKCU\Software\Test"
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('%systemroot%\system32\reg.exe query %hkey%') do (
    if "%%b"=="" (set "val=%%a") else (set "val=%%a %%b")
    echo.!val!
    echo %pathtosearch%
    echo !val!|%systemroot%\system32\findstr.exe /xr /c:\"^%pathtosearch%\[^\]+$\" && (
        echo "found"
    ) || (
        echo "not found"
    )
    echo.
)
exit 0
```

Comment: what error do you get? what is the input examples you have and expected results?

Comment: IMO this combination `findstr.exe /xr /c:\"^%pathtosearch%\[^\]+$\"` with double quotes inside `%pathtosearch%`can't return any result.

Comment: I do not get any errors. just no matches

Comment: What are you trying to remove, the `key`, the `value` or the `data`? Also, is there any reason why you're hiding the name of the software, _i.e the actual registry key you're searching under_?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, so this is a guess:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SPath=C:\Test folder\Newfolder"
Set "URKey=HKCU\Software\Test"
Set "FPath="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    ""%__AppDir__%Reg.exe" Query "%URKey%" /F "%SPath%" /D 2>Nul|"%__AppDir__%Find.exe" /I "%SPath%""
') Do If Not Defined FPath Set "FPath=%%A"
If Defined FPath (Call Set "FPath=%SPath%%%FPath:*%SPath%=%%"
    Echo Found) Else Echo Not Found 
If Defined FPath Echo(%FPath%
Pause
```

Comment: @Pahan, I've seen your edits, _(thank you)_, but as the question has changed radically from your initial posting, a simple modification of the above will not be possible. I will therefore revisit my answer, should I get time to address the updated requirements.